# How to render nested data elements using mustache js?

Tags: javascript, nested, mustache

I am using `txt.general_1.value` in template to display its value but it shows error in console `Can't find txt.general_1.value in [object Object]`
But if I just use `txt` in template, it displays `[object Object]`
Following is the code. Kindly help me in resolving this issue.
Please note that following code is just to reproduce the problem, actual data is different.

```
<script>
    var json_obj =
            {
            "all": [
                {
                    "row": "row",
                    "column": "col-md-6",
                    "txt": {
                        "general_1": {
                            "type": "a",
                            "value": "aaa - Hello world"
                        },
                        "general_2": {
                            "type": "b",
                            "value": "bbb - Hello world"
                        },
                        "general_3": {
                            "type": "c",
                            "value": "ccc - Hello world"
                        }                       
                    }
                }
            ]
        };
        
        
        var data = json_obj['all'][0];
        var template = "<div class=\"{{row}}\"><p class=\"{{column}}\">{{txt.general_1.value}}</p></div>";
        
        var text = Mustache.render(template, data);        
        $('#target').html(text);    
        
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the problem in the code snippet but didn't see any issue. The value is rendered correctly. Check the `json_obj` in your app, maybe it doesn't always contain the `txt.general_1.value` properties.

```js
var json_obj = {
  "all": [{
    "row": "row",
    "column": "col-md-6",
    "txt": {
      "general_1": {
        "type": "a",
        "value": "aaa - Hello world"
      },
      "general_2": {
        "type": "b",
        "value": "bbb - Hello world"
      },
      "general_3": {
        "type": "c",
        "value": "ccc - Hello world"
      }
    }
  }]
};


var data = json_obj['all'][0];
var template = "<div class=\"{{row}}\"><p class=\"{{column}}\">{{txt.general_1.value}}</p></div>";

var text = Mustache.render(template, data);
$('#target').html(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mustache@latest"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I was using ```https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/0.1/mustache.min.js``` due to which it was not working.